# Will two spacers between the cassette and the hub effect the chain line?

Tags: wheels, hub, cassette, chainline

So I have a set of custom wheels (White Industries T11 hubs) and when the cassette is correctly fastened to the hub with the single spacer provided the cassette cogs can be moved in the direction around the cassette (not laterally) ever so slightly. This causes an audible klank when the cogs are engaged and is generally not good. The solution from the wheel builder was to add an additional spacer between the hub and the cassette. Both spacers used were shipped with the White industry hub.

Using two spacers completely fixes the cassette slip issue but I'm wondering if it is effecting the chain line in some way? I have used the set of wheels on two different frames both with Ultegra group sets.

It could be me but there seems to be slightly more chain rub with the White Industry wheels than other wheels I have used like Mavics. Keep in mind that I am resetting both the front and rear derailers to accommodate the shift. Is it possible the spacers are just too wide? And are there different sizes for these spacers. Thanks in advance, any experience or advice would be appriciated.

I'm using a 10 speed setup, first bike is a Ridley X-fire (54) second bike is a Sworks Tarmac(58).

Comment: I'm not sure about White industry spacers in particular, but cassette spacers for shimano style freehub bodies come in a bunch of different widths - I would go to your LBS or perhaps White Industries and ask if they have different sizes - there could be a number of different factors as to why there is rub though - chainstay length, cassette size, chain length, BB spindle length to name a few.  Also - where exactly is it rubbing?

Comment: If two spacers together do the job, why not! Spacers are meant to compensate for the difference in width of cassette and hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured this out. I tracked down a 0.5mm spacer and when I went to switch out one of the spacers I realised they were almost the same size.

The White Industries spacer are just over 0.5mm. When I lined them up next to a Shimano 1mm spacer they were slightly taller.

Replaced the two White industries with one Shimano spacer re indexed, chain rub is completely gone.

So for those who are interested 0.2mm of spacing does throw out the chain line.

Thanks for all the input guys.

Moral of the story is use the spacers that come with the cassette not the hub!

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking about this from the wrong side of the cassette. All cassettes end at roughly the same point or the lockring wouldn't engage correctly. The spacers are to make sure there is significant compression, but because the cassette is still in the same spot relative to the drive side of the wheel the chainline shouldn't change.

That said you might want to pick up some different size spacers and see if you can change from 2mm (assuming two 1mm spacers) to 1.5mm. My guess is the amount you'd be able to move the cassette inward is very small, but might be significant. Most bike shops have a few spacer sizes on hand will sell them for $.5-$1 each IIRC.

Comment: Cheers good point. Will try a smaller spacer.